# SBT cannot import Kafka encoder/decoder classes

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

**Project setup:**

- 1 producer - serialises objects & sends bytes to Kafka
- 1 spark consumer - should use DefaultDecoder in kafka.serializer
  package to consume bytes

**Issue:**

- SBT imports correct libraries (kafka-clients + kafka_2.10) but is
  unable to find any classes in the kafka_2.10 jar.
- It seems as if it is searching under the wrong path
  (org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka instead of org.apache.kafka).

**Error message:**:

```
    object serializer is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka [error] 
import kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder.
```

**sbt-tree**

```
    [info]   +-org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.1
    [info]   | +-org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.1 [S] <-- **DefaultDecoder is in here 
but SBT can't find it (org.apache.kafka.serialization.DefaultDecoder)**
    [info]   | | +-org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.1
```

**built.sbt:**

```
  lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "org.RssReaderDemo",
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
)

resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"

val spark = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1"
val sparkStreaming = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1"
val sparkStreamKafka = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.1"

// Needed to be able to parse the generated avro JSON schema
val jacksonMapperAsl = "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13"

val scalactic = "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.6"
val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"

val avro = "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.8.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += spark,
    libraryDependencies += sparkStreaming,
    libraryDependencies += sparkStreamKafka,
    libraryDependencies += jacksonMapperAsl,
    libraryDependencies += scalactic,
    libraryDependencies += scalatest,
    libraryDependencies += avro
  )
```

Comment: Code that causes the error in SBT: import kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SBT. You likely have something like

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder
```

Because `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka` package exists, this import resolves to `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder`. You can import the correct class as follows: `import _root_.kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder`. See https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Language+FAQs#LanguageFAQs-HowdoIimport for more details on Scala imports.

Comment: Thanks - looks like that was the case.

Comment: Thank you. my code got compiled with your suggestion

Comment: Thank you - this got me going in the right direction.  I solved the issue by being a bit more explicit in my imports:

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

This would be my style preference, but both should work.

Comment: Thanks this post helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to "import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder" before "import org.apache.spark.streaming._". Order of import can resolve the issue.

Works -

```
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
```

Exception -

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
```